# 'DatabaseError: DPI-1050: Oracle Client library is at version 0.0 but version 11.2 or higher is needed' error is displayed in remote machine

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, robotframework, cx-oracle, oracleclient

I have installed python 3.7.4 (64 bit) and oracle client 12.2.0 (64 bit) in my machine which is having windows 10 operating system.

And I connect to database via robotframework-databaselibrary=1.2.4, but its displayed error as `DatabaseError: DPI-1050: Oracle Client library is at version 0.0 but version 11.2 or higher is needed`

Note: I have the same setup in my local and am able to connect to database successfully but when I implement the same setup and try to execute in remote machine its throwing error

Answer (score 2):

The likely issue is that you have an Oracle Client library that is too old earlier in the `PATH` than your 12.2 Oracle Client. If you upgrade to cx_Oracle 7.3 you should get an error message that says as much. Search all of the directories in your `PATH` environment variable for oci.dll and check the version of each of them. Frequently older versions of the Oracle Client library were placed in `C:\Windows\System32`.